# How to make VideoDisplay not to save all data it played?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, video, mxml

How to make s:VideoDisplay not to save all data it played?

Comment: Could you explain your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VideoDisplay does not save data while play streaming video. When you use progressive download mode all data always cached.
It's a VideoDisplay's (and VideoPlayer's) common behavior.